# visual studio 2019で作成したexeファイルのCRC値(CRC32C)を表示したい。

Tags: c++

visual studio 2019で作成したexeファイルのCRC値を
例)Tool CRC: 0x12345678
のように表示したいのですが、調べても以下のリンク先のような
https://gist.github.com/timepp/1f678e200d9e0f2a043a9ec6b3690635
CRCの算出方法が記載されているだけで、分からないので質問させていただきました。
ご助言の程宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: CRC って算出方式が一つじゃないし CRC 値をもってファイルの改変判定には使えないし、真にやりたいことは何ですか XY 問題だったりしませんか？

Comment: リンク先に出力するまでのソースも載っているようですが、何が判らないのかが分かりません。

Comment: 改竄を検知する目的ならば、exeファイルのハッシュ値を任意のツールで求めて、配布時に併記することが可能です。（例：OSDNではMD5、SHA1、SHA256でのハッシュ値をダウンロードページに表示している）ところで、添付しているソースコードはC++用のものですが、もしかして作成したexeファイルで、それ自身のexeファイルのCRC値を計算しようとしているのでしょうか。その場合、もしそのexeファイルが改竄されていても、正しいCRC値を表示するように改竄が可能なため、無意味となりますが……

Comment: コメントや回答で指摘されてますが、質問文の書き方が悪く閲覧者に正しく伝わっていないようです。本文には書かれていませんが、タイトルにCRC32Cと明示されています。要はIntelのSSE4.2で追加された`CRC32`命令で計算できる値になります。

Comment: この辺が関連しているかも。アルゴリズムに拘らなければ7zipで出来そうですが。[【Windows 11対応】MD5／SHA-1／SHA-256ハッシュ値を計算してファイルの同一性を確認する](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/0507/30/news017.html), [Any Built-In Checksum utility for Windows 10 using CRC-32?](https://superuser.com/q/1434718), [google/crc32c](https://github.com/google/crc32c), [google-crc32c 1.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-crc32c/), [crc32c 2.3](https://pypi.org/project/crc32c/)

Answer (score 0):

CRC値を算出アプリってのはぐぐってみるといくつかあるようです。
その実行ファイルをそのアプリにかければ、CRC値が出てきます